# Deleting old Docker images on a compute instance when updating using Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I've got a Cloud Build CI pipeline in which I'm building and pushing a new Docker image, then updating that image on a compute instance. Unfortunately the build happens quite frequently and I keep running out of disk space on the instance due to the old images piling up.

I can't seem to find a way to run a command on the instance as part of a Cloud Build step. If I could I suppose I could run a command to wipe old images.

Anyone have an idea about how to solve this, aside from manually having to SSH in to the instance a few times a day to clear the images?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `gcloud` [builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud)'s `ssh` command to access the instance.

You will need to ensure your Cloud Build job is permitted to access the instance.

However:

- How are you updating the image on the instance?
- Do you care if the newly updated image breaks?
- Do you need to be able to revert?
- Are you using [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/)?

Perhaps:

A simpler approach is to whack your instance each time you update the image. There is a concept of [immutable infrastructure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-immutable-infrastructure) that encourages creating new things rather than changing existing things.

Creating a new instance each time would:

- Obviate the issue of the build up old images on the instance
- Require you to have 'code' that would recreate the instance on demand
- If needed, permit you to rollover traffic from the old instance to the new